# Linear functional is continuous $\implies$ it is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous linear functional. Prove $f$ is bounded.

---

Since $f$ is continuous, $\forall \varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x-y)|=|f(z)|< \varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. We let $z=x-y$.

Can we just now let $\varepsilon = C \|x\|_X$ for some $C>0$ and then it is bounded?

Comment: Your question does not make sense for me... $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number: you can't say "let's take $\varepsilon = \mbox{something}$".

Comment: Im guessing you mean my answer doesn't make sense? Or is it the question? I copied it out correctly.  I was pretty unsure about that... hence why i made the thread.

Comment: let $T : X \to Y$ two normed vector spaces. if $\sup_{\|v\|=1} \|T v\| = \infty$ there is a sequence $(v_n) \in X$ such that $\|v_n\| \to 0$ but $\|T v_n\| \not\to 0$ (proof : for a fixed $\|u\|$, $\|T u\|$ can be arbitrary large)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous (at $0$), there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ such that $f(U)\subset(-1,1)$. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $\{x\in X|\|x\|\leq\delta\}\subseteq U$. Then, if $x\in X$ is such that $\|x\|\leq \delta$, we have $x\in U$, and hence, $|f(x)|\leq 1$. Since $\|\frac{\delta x}{\|x\|}\|=\delta$, it follows that for all $x\in X$ we have
$$
1\geq\left|f\left(\frac{\delta x}{\|x\|}\right)\right|=\frac{\delta}{\|x\|}|f(x)|\implies|f(x)|\leq\frac{1}{\delta}\|x\|.
$$
Therefore, $f$ is bounded.

Comment: so are you basically saying that you made epsilon equal to 1? Since the continuity of f a zero means for all epsilon, there exists delta positive such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon $ whenever $\|x\|<\delta $. So you just let epsilon equal 1?

Comment: Yes. The continuity of $f$ at $0$ tells us that $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ such that $\|x\|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$. So, we are allowed to use $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: OK how does $|\frac{\delta x}{\|x\|}| = \delta$?

Comment: $\|\frac{\delta x}{\|x\|}\|=|\frac{\delta}{\|x\|}|\|x\|=|\delta|\frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|}=\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Your estimate holds only in a neighborhood of $x$. Hence, you need can not control whether you may choose such a $C$ independent of $x$. You need to rely on the linearity of your operator in the following way:

By continuity of $f$ in $0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in X$ with $\Vert x \Vert_X <\delta$ holds

$$\vert f(x) - f(0) \vert \leq 1.$$

Using the linearity of $f$ we obtain

$$\vert f(x) \vert = \vert f(x) - 0 \vert =\vert f(x) - f(0) \vert \leq 1.$$

For $y\in X$, $y\neq0$ we get again by linearity of $f$

$$ \vert f(y) \vert  = \frac{\Vert y \Vert_X}{\delta} \cdot \underbrace{\Vert f\left(\frac{\delta y}{\Vert y \Vert_X} \right) \Vert_X}_{\leq 1}  \leq \frac{1}{\delta} \Vert y \Vert_X.$$

This is presicely the definition of bounded operator.