# A question about linear continous operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

**Theorem:** Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be linear operator.
Show that if $T$ is continous on X, then it is bounded.

*The attempt:*

if $T$ is continous on X, it is contionous at origin. Then,  $\forall x\in X $ we have $\lVert T(x)\rVert<\epsilon $ where $\lVert x\rVert <\delta$,

we must show that there is a $C>0$ such that for $\forall x\in X $,  $ \lVert A (x)\rVert <C \lVert x\rVert $. How?

Comment: This question has definitely been asked and answered here before.

Comment: I can' t find it. Could you share the link.

Comment: You can modify the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744323/linear-functional-is-continuous-implies-it-is-bounded) to obtain the proof you're looking for.

Comment: It may be the first theorem in any functional analysis book... what have you tried beside writing down the definition?

Comment: Not searching online, that's for sure.